# Laravel Routes not working like they're supposed to

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating an API to save and send events, nothing special about it... I've done it before but for some reason that I can't understand I'm getting this response from a normal route

I need to return an array of collections, nothing wrong about it, in tinker seems to work fine. But my problem doesn't involve data.

I want to do this:

**(in routes/api.php)**

```php
Route::get('activity/events', function() {
    return 'hi there';
});
```

But I got a 204 code in Postman with `my-site.test/api/activity/events`
The funny thing is, if I do this:

**(in routes/api.php)**

```php
Route::get('activity/events/{foo}', function() {
    return 'hi there';
});
```

I receive the message with no problem with `my-site.test/api/activity/events/bar`

Am I doing something wrong? I really don't know where to look for an answer

Thanks, everyone!

EDIT: I'm using the most up-to-date versions of everything

**Update**: The problem I experienced is related to the answer below. I had:

`Route::resource('/activity', 'ActivityController');`

before: `Route::prefix('activity') ...`

For anyone reading this, please don't make the same mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Status [204](https://httpstatuses.com/204) means that there is no additional content to send in the response payload body.

So try returning some JSON values like

```
Route::get('activity/events/{foo}', function() {
    return Response()->json(['success' => true], 200);
});
```

or try `Route::prefix`

```
Route::prefix('activity')->group(function () {
  Route::get('events', function() {
        return Response()->json(['success' => true], 200);
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but I'm having the same problem... When I use the function with the `/{foo}` bit at the end no problem at all, but if I remove it I get the same 204 error code

Comment: Okay could you try with route::prefix. update answer

Comment: I tried your solution with `Route::prefix` and it seems to work perfectly. Thank you so much, why was this a problem in the first place?

Comment: might be the sequence issue, every time your route with parameter gets executed first then the normal route